# Swagger UI not sending url params

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm building out an api for an app using MongoDB and mongoose and I'm using swagger UI to test it, I have made a delete route: 

`app.delete '/venues/:id', venueController.delete`
venueController.delete looks like this (in coffeescript):

```
exports.delete = (req, res) ->
  console.log req.params.id
  Venue.remove id: req.params.id
  .then (dbVenue) ->
    res.json dbVenue
  .catch (err) ->
    console.log err
    res.sendStatus(500).end err.message
```

In the swagger UI I enter an id and send the delete request, but the console.log for `req.params.id` just spits out `":id"` instead of the id I entered.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, I had to change the route in spec.json from `"/venues/:id"` to `"/venues/{id}"`